# Python converting txt file to list - optimization

Tags: python, file

So I have quite a big .txt file and Im trying to interpret the date with python. The file looks like this:

```
...
EUR/USD,20190801 00:00:00.142,1.10717,1.10718
EUR/USD,20190801 00:00:00.252,1.10717,1.10719
EUR/USD,20190801 00:00:02.580,1.10717,1.10718
EUR/USD,20190801 00:00:02.642,1.10716,1.10718
EUR/USD,20190801 00:00:03.580,1.10717,1.10718
...
```

and I need to extract last to values from it. So far I've tried this:

```
import datetime

x = 0
while x < 10:
with open('eurusd_ticks.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    text = lines[x]
    bid = text.split(',')[2]
    ask = text.split(',')[3]

    print(bid, ask, datetime.datetime.now())
    x += 1
```

it works well, this is the output:

```
1.10717 1.10718
 2019-11-20 09:19:21.641936
1.10717 1.10719
 2019-11-20 09:19:22.342880
1.10717 1.10718
 2019-11-20 09:19:22.968176
1.10716 1.10718
 2019-11-20 09:19:23.580704
1.10717 1.10718
 2019-11-20 09:19:24.189093
1.10716 1.10718
 2019-11-20 09:19:24.800332
1.10717 1.10718
 2019-11-20 09:19:25.413064
1.10715 1.10717
 2019-11-20 09:19:26.020620
1.10715 1.10715
 2019-11-20 09:19:26.629382
1.10715 1.10717
 2019-11-20 09:19:27.235971
```

But it takes almost 6 seconds to read just 10 lines, and I need to read 2,700,000 of them
(It will take me more than 31 days at this speed).

Maybe there is a way to optimize this process?

Comment: You are opening the file with the while loop... And you call readlines (which reads the whole file). This is very inefficient, try opening the file once, reading it once (with readlines) and then doing your while loop. For even better perf, do `for line in f` which while always give you one line at a time

Answer (score 4):

Instead of reading the entire file in memory (I would guess the entire file would take about 10 seconds with your current code) you should read line by line.

It's a small adjustment but will make a huge difference:

```py
import datetime


with open('eurusd_ticks.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        bid = line.split(',')[2]
        ask = line.split(',')[3]

        print(bid, ask, datetime.datetime.now())
```

For easier usage you should consider using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things to try...

1. Assuming you have enough memory, read the file using `read()` rather than `readlines()` and then split it later:

   ```
   with open('eurusd_ticks.txt', 'r') as f:
       data = f.read()
   text = data.splitlines()
   ```
2. `print` is quite slow, and you're doing it once per loop. Either don't do it, or print everything at the end, outside the loop
3. You're calling `split()` twice, you only need to call it once per loop and store it:

   ```
   for line in text:
       linesplit = line.split(",")
       bid = linesplit[2]
       ask = linesplit[3]
   ```